# iOS UITabBarController on 3.5 inch vs 4inch display

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

My app launches with a `LoginViewController` (`UIViewController`) which checks if the user is logged in. If user is logged in it uses a navigation controller to push a taskViewController (`UIViewController`) which has a table view within it. It displays a list of tasks.

WHen a user taps on a task, it launches taskDetailsViewController (`UIViewController`) in which i am programatically adding a `UITabBarController`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
 DetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
 CommentsViewController *commentsViewController = [[CommentsViewController alloc] init];
 FilesViewController *filesViewController = [[FilesViewController alloc] init];
 NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:detailsViewController, commentsViewController, filesViewController, nil];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

[self.view addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
}
```

This works fine on 4inch display but on a 3.5 inch display, the tab bars are not bottom aligned, they are kinda floating towards the bottom.

ANy idea what am i doing wrong here?

```
         --------------------------------------------
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |------------------------------------------|
         |           |                |             |
         |   Details |   Comments     |   Files     |
         |           |                |             |
         |           |                |             |
         |------------------------------------------|
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         |                                          |
         --------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up layout constraints. For your case, the easiest is to create a constraint that sets the distance to the bottom of the screen to 0. For example:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary =
            NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.tabBarController.view);
NSArray *constraints =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[tabBar]-|"
                        options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

This says to vertically flush the tab bar view to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Hi Rikkles,I added the following but to no affect.UIView *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary =
    NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tabBar);
    NSArray *constraints =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[tabBar]-|"
                                            options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

Comment: Oh sorry you actually did that. So the problem is somewhere else, probably in your upstream view. Are you sure that the view is using the full screen?

Comment: Rikkles, how can i make sure the view is using full screen? Looks like it may not be. I added a new subview (full width & height) to the view and then added the tabBarController to it. It worked but the system gave a run time constraint exception.

Comment: Then you probably have unwanted constraints that trigger. Check the constraints of this superview.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `tabBarController` can be used as `rootViewController`
To determine if the user login is successful, the switching rootViewController = tabBarController

Comment: I need the rootViewController to be the navigation controller so the user can navigate back from taskDetailsViewController(UITabBarController) to tasksViewController(Table View)